# Is there a Mac+xcode virtual lab online?

Tags: xcode

I'm sure most of you heard of Microsoft Virtual Labs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff640662

You can connect remotely to msdn servers and practice development on vs2010,sql server 2008 R2..etc

Is there something like that in mac world with xcode? I want to practice on development with iphone and take online labs,I don't have a mac for now.

P.S: I think there isn't such a thing in mac world but just wanted to try my luck,hopefully someone might prove me wrong,I searched online but didn't find such a thing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can give http://virtualmacosx.com a try.  They provide a full online instance of Mac OS X with the Xcode Development Environment pre-installed.  It could be a good option for someone looking to experiment with Xcode before taking the plunge on a Mac.

Comment: It looks promising except that it's not free since it's a third party,I have to pay about 10-20$ per month just for experimenting xcode ,students can't afford that,I wished Apple has online labs like Microsoft and for free :) ,however this proved that virtual desktop for Mac OS online is exists now,thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 9):

http://www.macincloud.com/ Looks like another option, but I'm not sure how good they are. The Web site is pretty informative though.

Comment: It's costs way more than http://virtualmacosx.com [20$-35$], maybe because it provides much more than just xcode i.e support corona,phonegap and other sdks,still worth to check it out

Answer (score -9):

The best site I have ever experienced for virtual machines is
[Virtual machine](http://virtualdesktop.org/complete/)

Follow the link and you can see amazing `OS` in that links

TO try above you need to pay. But it is for free.

[Virtual mac os online free](http://virtualdesktop.org/complete/)

Comment: Those are not VMs (just a vast collection of screen captures). You can't do anything useful with them (like actually run Xcode and compile code).

Comment: As @AndrewMedico pointed out,these are a vast collection of screenshots nothing more

Comment: This is not a virtual machine, only images.

Comment: Images can help solving any problem if they show the steps that following them solves the problem at last, but I can just google all these images shown in your link which do not show any steps to follow at all and so they are unhelpful in solving Ala' Alnajjar's problem at all.